# Double function on click event in javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i add a double function on the same click button without colliding with the first function.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', drop);

function drop(){
items.style.display = 'block';
items.style.display = 'none';
```

drop down menu in html.

Comment: Change the name of the second function from `drop` to something else or use an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind the function using `addEventListener` multiple times.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', job1);
btn.addEventListener('click', job2);



function job1(){
  console.log('Job 1 triggered');
}

function job2(){
  console.log('Job 2 triggered');
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your functions in a function:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {drop(), other()});

function drop(){
 // items.style.display = 'block';
//  items.style.display = 'none';
  console.log('drop triggered');
}

function other(){
  console.log('other triggered');
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Why bind a function to button which in turn calls other functions when you can directly bind the respective functions to the button itself?

Comment: @Salvino hey mate, why not, it works like your example does, just another way of doing same thing :) for example if you need more functions on same click even, let's say 5, you will need to add 5 event listeners and this way you just call 5 functions from one event listener, cheers :)

Comment: Thats guys btw i did  solve the problem with an if statement inside the onlick event.